# Change cell decimals based on itself

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2016

I want to change the amount of decimals places in a cell-based on its own value.

For this example. If the cell has a value of zero, I want 1 or 2 decimal places else I want the full decimal places.

[image: before]

So if the value is zero:

[image: after]

I have tried this:

```
=IF(F9=0,ROUND(F9, 2), F9)
```

This is what it looks like normal

With no success. Is this possible?

Comment: what is shown is formatting.  Formulas cannot change formatting.  One can use Conditional formatting.  Format the cells with the 8 decimals.  Then use conditional formatting to change to `0.0` when the cell = `0`.

Comment: @ScottCraner Thank you ! it worked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The actual cell that contains a value cannot be altered with excel formulas. You need a programming language for that, e.g. VBA. The single other alternative is conditional formatting. *(Hmm... might be possible to use what is below in a conditional formatting formula... haven't tried that!)*

But the value from that cell can be used in a formula, the result will then be visible in the cell that contains the formula.

e.g. to display the value from A2, using a calculated amount/count of decimals you might use this formula in any other cell:
`=TEXT(A2,"0."&REPT("0",INT(LOG(A2))+2))`

1. The first `A2` is the value to display
2. `"0."` is literal, i.e. used as is
3. `... & ...` as used here, is a shorthand for `CONCATENATE("0.", REPT(...))`
4. `REPT("0",...` repeat `0` as many times as `INT(LOG(A2))+2)` ends up
   be.
5. `LOG(A2)` of course tells "how many digits" (=the magnitude of the number) there is in the number
   shown in A2.
6. `INT(...)` removes all decimals (keep the INTeger part)... and
   finally
7. `+2` simply adds two more decimals to show.

So: single digit numbers will have two decimals, double digit numbers (10-99) will have three, 100 to 999 will have three, and so on.

This works up to at least 16 decimals, if I'm not too wrong. (I believe Excel uses 16 digit precision in it's numbers).

If one places a `MIN(7,...)` around `INT(...)` the amount of decimals will stop growing as there is `7` of them.